# Addition in Java 8 using BinaryOperator

Tags: java, addition, binary-operators

```
  package com.operators;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;

    public class TotalCost {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            double mealCost = scan.nextDouble(); // original meal price
            int tipPercent = scan.nextInt(); // tip percentage
            int taxPercent = scan.nextInt(); // tax percentage
            scan.close();

            Map<Double,Double> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put(mealCost, (double)tipPercent);
            map.put(mealCost, (double)taxPercent);

            BinaryOperator<Double> opPercent = (t1,t2) -> (t1*t2)/100;
            BinaryOperator<Double> opSum = (t1,t2) -> (t1+t2);   
            calculation(opPercent,map);
        }

        public static void calculation(BinaryOperator<Double> opPercent , Map<Double,Double> map) {
            List<Double> biList = new ArrayList<>();
            map.forEach((s1,s2)-> biList.add(opPercent.apply(s1, s2)));
        }
    }
```

1. I have the below problem which I am trying to solve in Java 8 using BinaryOperator.There are three inputs to this application [mealCost(double), tipPercent(int),taxPercent(int)].
2. I am trying to calculate the below values :

   ```
   tip = (mealCost*tipPercent)/100;
   tax = (mealCost*taxPercent)/100;
   TotalCost = mealCost+tip +tax;
   ```
3. I am unable to pass an integer input to the apply method of BinaryOperator. Also the calculated value into biList is not proper.
   Below is my code

Comment: you also might want to use `DoubleBinaryOperator` which uses primitive values instead of the `Double` wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting the same key twice in a Map, so the second value overrides the first value. I don't think a `Map` is appropriate for these calculations. You can use a `List<SomePairType>` instead.

Or keep `mealCost` in one variable and the other values in a `List<Double>`:

```
    public static void calculation(BinaryOperator<Double> opPercent, Double cost, List<Double> rates) {
        List<Double> biList = new ArrayList<>();
        rates.forEach(d-> biList.add(opPercent.apply(cost, d)));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have already told you the root cause of the error in calculation. Regarding the second part of your question:

> I am unable to pass an integer input to the apply method of
>   BinaryOperator

This is because you have declared that your `BinaryOperator` takes `Double` as the input parameter type and return type. [`BinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) takes only one Type as parameter and which is the type of both the input parameters as well as the return type, so if you have `Double` as method parameters and `Double` as the return type also, you can decide to use `BinaryOperator`. If you have multiple types as parameters and return type, you can consider using [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html).

```
BiFunction<Double, Integer, Double> opPercent = (t1,t2) -> (t1*t2)/100;
```

Here we are saying that the input parameters are Double and Inetger corresponding to the mealCost and taxPercent and the return type is a Double.

You can even define your own functional interface with more number of parameters  like in example below:

```
public class TotalCost {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      double mealCost = scan.nextDouble(); // original meal price
      int tipPercent = scan.nextInt(); // tip percentage
      int taxPercent = scan.nextInt(); // tax percentage
      scan.close();

      TriFunction<Double, Integer, Integer, Double> calcCost = (cost, tipPct, taxPcnt) -> 
                                        (cost + (cost * tipPct/100) + (cost * taxPcnt/100));
      Double totalBill = calculation(calcCost, mealCost, tipPercent, taxPercent);
      System.out.println(totalBill);
   }

    public static Double calculation(TriFunction<Double, Integer, Integer, Double> calcCost , 
                                       Double mealCost, Integer tipPct, Integer taxPct) {
       return calcCost.apply(mealCost, tipPct, taxPct);
        }
  }

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface TriFunction<T,U,V,R> {
        R apply(T t, U u, V v);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the values for the same key in the map. So the initial value was getting overridden by the new value.

Try the code below

```
package com.operators;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;

public class TotalCost {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double mealCost = scan.nextDouble(); // original meal price
        int tipPercent = scan.nextInt(); // tip percentage
        int taxPercent = scan.nextInt(); // tax percentage
        scan.close();

        Map<Double,Double> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put(mealCost, (double)taxPercent + (double)tipPercent);

        BinaryOperator<Double> opPercent = (t1,t2) -> (t1*t2)/100;
        BinaryOperator<Double> opSum = (t1,t2) -> (t1+t2);   
        calculation(opPercent,map);
    }

    public static void calculation(BinaryOperator<Double> opPercent , Map<Double,Double> map) {
        List<Double> biList = new ArrayList<>();
        map.forEach((s1,s2)-> biList.add(opPercent.apply(s1, s2)));
    }
}
```